# select columns from different tables with different data type columns

Tags: sql, select, join

I want to know how to write a query, which selects specific columns(not common) from 2 different tables and combine them together.

I tried this, but didn't work:

```
SELECT ii.sequence
FROM Costs ii
WHERE ii.order_ID IN (SELECT book.order_ID
                      FROM BookInfo ci
                      WHERE ii.order_ID = ci.order_ID)
UNION
SELECT ft.released_title
FROM FinishedBook ft
WHERE ft.version IN (SELECT ii.iiversion
                     FROM Costs ii
                     WHERE ii.iiorder_ID IN (SELECT ci.order_ID
                                             FROM BookInfo ci
                                             WHERE ii.iiorder_ID = ci.order_ID))
ORDER BY sequence;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this a case of joining these tables and calling `Distinct` to avoid duplicates?
Try this:

```
select Distinct a.Sequence, b.RELEASED_TITLE
from IncludedIn a inner join FinishedTrack b
 on a.OriginatesFrom = b.IIOriginatesFrom 
 Inner join CdInfo c on a.IIALBUM_ID = c.ALBUM_ID
Order By a.Sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

For MSSQL Server, Use `Join` to get the result.

```
SELECT I.Sequence, F.Released_Title FROM FinishedTrack AS F
INNER JOIN IncludedIn AS I ON I.ORIGINATESFROM = F.IIORIGINATESFROM
INNER JOIN CdInfo AS A ON A.ALBUM_ID = I.IIALBUM_ID
ORDER BY I.Sequence DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This query might work for you

```
SELECT IncludedIn.SEQUENCE, FinishedTrack.RELEASED_TITLE
FROM FinishedTrack
INNER JOIN IncludedIn
ON FinishedTrack.ORIGINATESFROM=IncludedIn.IIORIGINATESFROM and
FinishedTrack.VERSION=IncludedIn.IIVERSION order by FinishedTrack.SEQUENCE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a JOIN instead of a UNION:

```
SELECT ii.sequence, ft.released_title
FROM IncludedIn ii
INNER JOIN CdInfo ci ON ii.iialbumid = ci.album_id
INNER JOIN FinishedTrack ft on ft.originatesfrom = ii.iioriginatesfrom
ORDER BY ii.sequence;
```